# How to replace a folder in a pending cl in p4?

Tags: replace, directory, perforce

I want to replace folder A in P4 by another folder A.

The two folders have different files and sub folders.

I know, we can do it by deleting old folder A then adding new folder A.

But, can I do it with only one step in a pending changelist ?

As following result in that pending cl:

If this file is in old folder, but not in new folder, then it is marked by "delete".

If this file is in new folder, but not in old folder, then it is marked by "add".

If this file is in new folder and also in old folder, then it is marked by "modify".

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Are both these folders under source control?

That is, are you trying to make //depot/folder/A contain what //depot/other/A_prime contains?

If so, consider using 'p4 copy':

```
p4 copy //depot/other/A_prime/... //depot/folder/A/...
```

If the other folder A is just something you have on your hard disk, then consider using 'reconcile':

```
p4 edit //depot/folder/A/...
rm -r /path/to/depot/folder/A/*
cp -r /path/to/other/folder/A/* /path/to/depot/folder/A
p4 reconcile -aed //depot/folder/A/...
```

I kind of like the 'p4 copy' approach, myself, so I'd be tempted to check that other folder into Perforce (in a different location in the repository, naturally), so that I could then run 'p4 copy'.

Comment: It works. I made it by option "Reconcile Offline Work..." in p4v. Sorry, I cannot give a vote now. Later I will do it when I am rich. Thank you.